# ConTeXt command list

Tags: context, lua

How can I get a “machine readable” version of the [ConTeXt command
list](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf)?

Ideally, I would like to get a Lua table in some reasonable format,
listing all commands and their main attributes (like argument names
and their delimiters, allowed keys and values, and if possible some
documentation).  For instance:

```lua
{
  alpha = {
    symbol = "α",
    arguments = {}
  },
  at = {
    arguments = {
      [1] = {meta = "text", optional = true},
      [2] = {meta = "text", optional = true},
      [3] = {meta = "reference", delimiters = {"[", "]"}}
    },
    summary = "Some short explanation, if available",
    documentation = "Link to the ConTeXt reference manual or wiki"
  },
  commandwithkeyvaluearguments = {
    arguments = {
      [1] = {
        meta = "options",
        delimiters = {"[", "]"},
        keys = {--[[table describing the possible keys and values]]},
      }
    },
    summary = "Some short explanation, if available",
    documentation = "Link to the ConTeXt reference manual or wiki"
  },
  ...
}
```

This would be useful in a library to compute code completions and
help, like [this one](https://github.com/astoff/digestif).

If this table could be computed in `texlua` directly from the local
ConTeXt installation, it would be even nicer.  Otherwise, a file
containing the data will do the job.

Comment: There is a directory called `interface` which contains all the .xml files.

Comment: You can load the XML file which contains *all* the interfaces and try to serialize it into a table (http://dpaste.com/1M47RBN, expires in 7 days).  When I executed this it froze my PC, because this file it very large. Be warned!